# Php function missing one record

Tags: php

I have a php function

```
function getMembersByFamilyNumber($familyNumber){
        $html = "";
        $query = db_execute("SELECT * FROM `family_members` WHERE `family_number` = '".$familyNumber."' and `isActive`= '1' and `isDelete`= '0' ORDER BY id DESC");
        $check = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        if ($check) {
            while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){         
                extract($result);               
                $html.='
                    <li>
                        <time class="cbp_tmtime" datetime="2013-04-10 18:30"><span>'.$familyNumber.'</span> <span>'.$relation_head.'</span></time>
                        <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-phone"></div>
                        <div class="cbp_tmlabel">
                            <h2>'.$name.'</h2>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" onclick="editPageContent(\'editpagecontent\',\'editMember\',\''.$id.'\');">Edit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" onclick="deletePageContent(\'deletepagecontent\',\'deleteHead\',\''.$id.'\');">Delete</button>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Age: '.$age.' years old</li>
                                <li>Education: '.$education.'</li>
                                <li>Occupation: '.$occupation.'</li>
                                <li>Alive: '.$alive.'</li>
                                <li>Phone: '.$phone.'</li>
                                <li>CNIC: '.$cnic.'</li>
                            </ul> 
                        </div>
                    </li>
                ';
            }
            return $html;
            exit;
        }else{
            return "<li><h2>No members found.</h2></li>";
        }

    }
```

Is is returning only one record, but in database there is two records against this query, whenever i i execute this query in MySQL it returning two rows, but whenever i run this code it return only second record, missing first record, every time it missing first record. means if my table have 5 records this function returns 4 records and miss 1st record. Why this happens? help me.

Comment: In your loop you are setting the value of the `$html` each time through the loop, rather than appending it.  That means your last record will be the only one displayed.

Comment: Perhaps because you call #check=mysql_fetch_assoc($query), which removes first entry, then later call $result = mysql_fectch...... You should be able to get rid of the $check=mysql.. part and the "if" statement, and use everything in the while.

Comment: No, I  m not seeting value of $html, i m appending it by $html.=""

Comment: Instead of the CHECK try this:
  if (mysql_num_rows($query) >0)
  then go to the WHILE loop with undisturbed data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows($query)` not use

`$check = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        if ($check) {`

This is correct solution:

`if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){`

Comment: ok i removed my $check statement, but still same issue, why it is missing my 1st record?

Comment: Because, `$check = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);` get row from query data and set pointer to next value.